# Understanding a proof of Cauchy's Theorem

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I was reading [this](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/cauchypf.pdf) proof of Cauchy's Theorem, which states that if a prime $p$ divides the order of a group, there exists an element in that group of order $ p$ .

I think I understood it pretty well, except where it briefly proves the special case when $p=2$.

I fail to see how this is necessary for the rest of the proof, because I can't find any logical argument that doesn't hold when $p=2$. I guess the question I'm asking is why do we need to consider $p=2$ as a special case instead of proving it with the general solution?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proving the $p=2$ case separately was not necessary. Note that it's not included under the ''proof" heading. You can run the general proof with $p=2$ and everything works fine.

I suspect the only reason the $p=2$ case was given separately was for some expository reason. Perhaps as a warm-up to the proof, or to contrast the special $p=2$ case with the general case.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that the proof heading came after it. I feel dumb now, thanks for clarifying this though

Answer (score 1):

It holds for $p=2$

Identity is the only element of order $1$, hence other element must have order $2$  .  If it is not of order $2$ , then it's inverse which is distinct from identity and the element itself will also be an element of the group, contradicting that the group has order $2$.

To see the bigger picture, it is often helpful to see some spacial cases. I hope Conrad tried same thing to give some intuition at least.

Comment: Oh I understood that the theorem works when p=2, I just don't understand why proving this special case individually was necessary since it seems to have been proved in the rest of the theorem.